# Mariadb version

Tags: 18.04

I wanted to see how to install version 10.3.12 of mariadb, if someone can help me and I tried to add the libraries that it asks for, it still won't let me download that version

Comment: You should edit your question and include more details and context.  You should tell us why you think you need this specific version. You should also provide clear details about the exact steps you are taking and the exact response from your device. Include all error messages verbatim and unredacted.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider upgrading Ubuntu. In 20.04 (focal) it has MariaDB 10.3, so there is no need to install from source. Especially with a DBMS, I would think twice before trying to install from source.

Comment: If you need to run specific versions of MariaDB, the only consistent mechanism to do so is with a Docker container 

Comment: I apologize for the incompetence I am new to using linux and the forums do not know very well how the subject is going

Comment: Well, I need to install a previous version of mariadb because I also have to install an old version of Moodle, a platform that is used for teaching, the version I want to install is 3.6.1 and it asks me as a mandatory requirement Mariadb 5.5.31 and Php 7.0.0, all this to later create a backup on a new Moodle platform

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?